# How can I solve this reference error for java-script file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am passing the name as the element through an server.js to index.ejs but getting an error as name not defined.

I am able to print hi when I am not rendering any name but with a name, it gives the error.

I am new to coding.

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()

app.set('view engine','ejs')


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index.ejs',{ name: 'V'})
})

app.listen(3000)
```

```html
<h1>HI <%= name%> </h1>
```

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\views\index.ejs:1
 >> 1| <h1>HI <%= name%> </h1>

name is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:10:26)
    at returnedFn (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\server.js:5:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\van\Documents\Testing Node JS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove .ejs from the file extension in your route? Also, do you have ejs installed as a dependency?

Comment: @JayKariesch - yes it worked without .ejs extension. Thanks a lot for the advice. I was following a tutorial he used index.ejs not sure how his code was running. This was my first question on stack overflow. You guys are awesome.